# circular dependency detected in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am facing circular dependency issue in my modal where there is signup form and a login button in the signup form for already registered user. Also login form has then signup button for not already registered user. I have heard es6 solves circular dependency issue but i am still getting it. How can i solve this issue?

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   app/containers/LoginContainer/index.js ->
>   app/containers/Register/index.js ->
>   app/containers/LoginContainer/index.js
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   app/containers/Register/index.js ->
>   app/containers/LoginContainer/index.js ->
>   app/containers/Register/index.js

```
import Login from "containers/LoginContainer";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  showDialog: dialog => dispatch(showDialog(dialog)),
  hideDialog: () => dispatch(showDialog("null"))
});

class Register extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { show_password, user } = this.state;
    return (
      <Modal show onHide={() => this.props.hideDialog()}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group form-block">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="first_name"
              className="form-control-form "
              placeholder="First Name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group form-block">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="last_name"
              className="form-control-form "
              placeholder="Last Name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group form-block">
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              className="form-control-form "
              placeholder="Email"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group form-block">
            <input
              type={show_password ? "text" : "password"}
              name="password"
              className="form-control-form"
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <Modal.Footer>
              <a
                className="btn-gst"
                onClick={() => this.props.showDialog(<Login />)}
              >
                Login
              </a>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}



import Register from 'containers/Register';

<Modal show onHide={() => this.props.hideDialog()}>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group form-block">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="username"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group form-block">
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="checkbox meta">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" /> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  <Modal.Footer>
        <a
          className="btn-gst"
          onClick={() => this.props.showDialog(<Register />)}
        >
          Sign Up
        </a>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Comment: It's sometimes OK to have circular dependencies. ES6 modules are designed to handle them.

Comment: But i am getting big warning. The user will see that in console.